# Android AVD - USB Port

Tags: android, usb, google-api, android-virtual-device

I'm new in Android Programming.

I'm trying to write an app that uses USB to communicate with a device (Read/Write). I'm using Android SDK 2.3.3 (API 10). My project is set to use Google API. I created AVD using `AVD Manager` from eclipse for Google API.

Now When I'm using:

`mUsbAccessory = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();`

`mUsbAccessory` is `null` because no devices attached to AVD. Is it possible to make AVD to use one of the USB port from my computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator does not have usb support (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#limitations).